# Unable to select multiple rows in a WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, selecteditem

Even though I've got `SelectionMode="Extended"` and `SelectionUnit="FullRow"` set, when I debug the `SelectionChanged` event, there's always only one selected item in `SelectedItems`.

This is my `DataGrid`:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="0" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="5,5,5,0"
        Name="dgrMembersClub1" ItemsSource="{Binding .}" CanUserAddRows="False"
        SelectionMode="Extended" SelectionUnit="FullRow" SelectionChanged="Grid_SelectionChanged">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Joining" >
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Header="Surname" Binding="{Binding Surname}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Header="Club" Binding="{Binding Club_Id, Converter={StaticResource ClubName}}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Header="City" Binding="{Binding City}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

And my `Grid_SelectionChanged` event:

```
private void Grid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    DataGrid grid = (DataGrid)sender;
    var test = grid.SelectedItems; //Count == 1 (always)
}
```

I do have Triggers set (in App.xaml) that change the background and foreground brushes for selected and alternating rows. If that's relevant, please let me know and I'll add the code.

*** EDIT ***

While you're at it, I could use some help getting the checkbox in the cell template to work too. Pretty please :)

Comment: You can bind to SelectedItems.

Comment: @GayotFow: That would remove all items that are not selected in the datagrid, right? That's not really what I want. The problem is I can't select more than 1 row.

Comment: No, nothing gets removed from the grid.  It's an array of selected items.  I bind to it all the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SelectedItems property of the DataGrid contains a list of, well, selected items...

```
private void DataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender,
    SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // ... Get SelectedItems from DataGrid.
    var grid = sender as DataGrid;
    var selected = grid.SelectedItems;

    foreach (var item in selected)
    {
        var dog = item as Dog;
    }
}
```

This indicative event handler gets the SelectedItems and loops through it.

However, there's a caveat:

> "If the SelectionMode property is set to Single, the SelectedItems
>   list will contain only the SelectedItem property value."

Source:  [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.selecteditems(v=vs.95).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.selecteditems%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

The SelectedItems property inherits from IList so it is possible to cast it and perform LINQ operations on it as well.  It also works fine with non-contiguous selections.

More tips at http://www.dotnetperls.com/datagrid

Comment: Thanks, I'm not unfamiliar with the idea of datagrids and item selection. The problem is, I'm more familiar with mobile platforms like Windows Phone and Windows RT where selecting multiple items doesn't require the CTRL-key to be pressed. I'll just have to define a collection where I can add/remove items that get clicked. That usually creates flickering. But still, thanks for the answer, it got me thinking ;)

Comment: Help is on the way.  My book on data grid recipes illuminates lots of different patterns that can be used as templates.

Answer (score 0):

```
private IEnumerable<DataGridRow> GetDataGridRows(DataGrid grid)
{
    var itemsSource = grid.ItemsSource as IEnumerable;
    if (null == itemsSource) yield return null;
    foreach (var item in itemsSource)
    {
        var row = grid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item) as DataGridRow;
        if (null != row & row.IsSelected) yield return row;
    }
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var rows = GetDataGridRows(dgv_Students);
    string id; //Sample =>"85-999888-2"
    foreach (DataGridRow dr in rows)
    {
        id = (dr.Item as tbl_student).code_meli;
        MessageBox.Show(id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a recommendation: you should add some high level explanation in your answer.