# How can I select rows from two DataGrids at the same time in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have 2 DataGrids put in the same Grid in WPF project, when I select row of the DataGrid 2, the selected row in DataGrid 1 becomes unselected and vice versa
I need a way to select rows from theses 2 grids at the same time

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to select multiple rows in a WPF DataGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24334451/unable-to-select-multiple-rows-in-a-wpf-datagrid)

Comment: The styling that makes a selected row turn blue differentiates between a row that's selected and focussed and one that's selected but not focussed. Only one can have focus. Are you sure both rows aren't still selected? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7998112/datagrids-selected-row-color-when-inactive